# Store application state other than user

Tags: ember.js, state, ember-simple-auth

I am familiar with the method of using an initializer to inject the current user into the ember-simple-auth created session object and am using is successfully. How would I go about storing/persisting other application states for the logged in user?

For example, in my application we have *workspaces*. A user can have many workspaces, and we need to define which workspace they're currently signed into. During a session, the user should be able to "sign-out" of the workspace and choose a different one. We also may need to store the id of the workspace they last signed into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store anything you want in the session (as long as it's something that survives a `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse` roundtrip), e.g. in your routes:

```
this.get('session').set('currentWorkspaceId', workspace.get('id'));
```

Comment: Thanks @marcoow. What would you recommend for persisting the last logged into workspace outside of the session scope?

Comment: I'd use either ´sessionStorage` (which is per tab/window) or `localStorage` (which is synced across tabs/windows).